# Can I name an object attribute to mimic a method call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm building a new app in RoR and have used traditional attribute naming conventions in the past.  In the name of readability however, I've started to think about using more descriptive object attributes.  For example, instead of `if user.special_needs == true ...`, i could name the attribute 'has_special_needs', which could then read `if user.has_special_needs ...`.

While this makes my code much easier to read, it looks suspiciously similar to a method call, which made me think it might be confusing and/or I might be stepping over the naming convention lines.  After much research, I haven't found any solid argument for either option.  Since this also treads on DB naming conventions (a topic I know little about), I was hoping to get some advice.

Thanks

Comment: What does it matter if it is a method or not? How is it suspicious anyway? Do you thing your user will not have special needs if it is a method ;) ?

Comment: I simply want to follow proper naming conventions and was asking if this crosses the line between attribute and method name

Comment: What makes you think it isn’t actually a method call in the first place? (Hint: it is.)

Comment: very good point Andrew, but that also leaves me with a table column named has_special_needs vs special_needs.  Does this step on DB naming conventions?  Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to wrap up things, it's very acceptable to create this kind of methods:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def has_special_needs
    self.special_needs == true
  end
end
```

You can also use question marks (?) and bangs (!) to make code more readeable:

```
def has_special_needs?
  self.special_needs == true
end
```

But in this particular example `user.special_needs` is true or false right? So you can just use an alias:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :has_special_needs?, :special_needs
  ...
end

# Then:
if @mymodel.has_special_needs?
  ...
end
```

Comment: Is this a better solution?  Without looking a Model, you still wouldn't be able to distinguish between the two.  Is there a benefit to an alias in this situation?

Comment: If you don't want to "search and replace" in all your code, I think this is the best solution. Its always better to have clear names for your attributes and methods, Ruby code should be easy to read.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the ruby convention of using a `?` to denote a boolean method.

Comment: Thank Benjamin.  This is the convention I have used in the past, although do I even need to alias the attribute at that point?

Comment: Welcome Remy, I don't pretend to give you a solution you can copy-paste in your code, I am just trying to let you know the different techniques you could use. Now you are the only one able to decide which one fit better with your code :) Cheers